# How do I remove leaves from my tree point cloud data using Meshlab?

Tags: graphics, meshlab

I have point cloud data of tree and  I want to just keep the skeleton part and remove all the leaves portion. Though I am able to do it using Select connected region, but it will require a lot of time as there are thousands of leaves. Is there any method, where I can remove the whole upper crown of tree in just one go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the button "Select Vertexes" and select a region of them. Or use the button "Select Vertex Cluster" and hold the left click while you move the pointer to select a cluster of vertices. After that you can use the button "Delete the current set of selected vertices".